# Charge LiPo 5S with 18.5V laptop power supply

Tags: power-supply, lipo, laptop

Is it possible to charge 5000mah 5s lipo pack with cheap $10 HP laptop power supply without special LiPo charger? Just by connecting the leads. The charge rate would be less than 1C.

- Power supply is 18.5V / 3.5A / 65W / AC/DC
- Battery is 5S1P / 18.5v / 5Cell

Here is the battery - 
[Turnigy 5000mAh 5S 20C Lipo Pack](http://hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__9174__Turnigy_5000mAh_5S_20C_Lipo_Pack.html)

Comment: Other issues aside, the charge rate will not be less than 1C. Your power supply is not limited to 3.5 A, 3.5 A is the point beyond which it may stop working or start burning.

Comment: Could you post the datasheet for the battery pack, please?  It would help us explain you what you should expect and why.  In the meantime, here's a write-up about [safety of Lithium batteries](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/safety_concerns_with_li_ion).

Comment: @Damien, is it possible to limit the current by adding some "current limiter"? (if such a thing exists)

Comment: @Nick Alexeev, I added the url.

Comment: Don't do it.  Least worst thing that can happen is that it will not charge.  Next least worst thing is that you will degrade the battery.  The most worst thing is that you will start a fire.

Comment: @beemaster yes, current limiters exist, but why not just use a LiPo charger? With a current limiter you would have something that could *sort of* charge your batteries on the proverbial desert island, with *some* risk of breaking things / making fire. Not worth using regularly. A safer question that *could* be worth researching is whether you can get away with using a simpler non-balancing LiPo charger *some of the time*, and the answer might be yes, if proper care is taken and your cells have protection circuits.

Comment: But again, what's the goal? If you're just trying to save money, don't. You won't save any in the long term considering your batteries will suffer.

Comment: My goal was to have compact charger that I can use at work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is no!  A 5S lithium battery will require a voltage of 21 volts to fully charge.  There are other problems that you would run into by just plugging in that power source such as limiting the currents so that the power supply doesn't burn out, but if you are serious about charging that battery, it just can't be done at that voltage with that laptop power supply.

To charge a lithium  battery you need:

1) supply a constant controlled current appropriate for that battery until each cell reaches 4.2 volts.

2) At 4.2 volts, supply constant voltage of 4.2 volts per cell and allow the current to drop as the battery saturates and fills up.

3)  Ideally this should be done with a charger that can actually charge and monitor each individual cell versus charging all 5 at once to avoid imbalances

4) lithium iron and the older lithium ion use different voltages! 4.2 is for the commonly used lipo and I used it only as an example for the lithium chemistry in general.